# Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in core php

Tags: php, xampp, htdocs, undefined-function, magic-quotes

I am facing these problem.I am using PHP 7. other project rather than core PHP runs very good but if I want to run the core PHP project it shows the following problem.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\framework.php:21 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(22): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\framework.php on line 21

According to this site:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php
It says that This function was DEPRECATED in **PHP 5.3.0**, and REMOVED as of **PHP 7.0.0**

any answer? waiting for the answer and thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't exist anymore. And it's neither needed anymore. Magic quotes are gone.

Comment: I am facing this problem. how could I solve this problem.
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\framework.php:21 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(22): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\framework.php on line 21

Comment: the question asked by Mario doesn't work in mine condition

Comment: What "doesn't work" with just removing it?